# Rails ActiveRecord Rollback didn't happen where it is expected to happen when there is an exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, rubygems

Let's say I have a object named book.
once book.save! is given all the model callbacks will be triggered according to the rails order defined.
In my case API request timeout exception happened in the middle of an around_save callback. My understanding is since the after_commit was not triggered this transaction should be rolled back. But in my case the data got stored into the DB. What am I missing. Can someone please help. I'm beginner to rails.

Not sure on how to understand this. Using ruby 2.7.5 and rails 4.2.11

Comment: Is the request timeout exception triggered by your code or does it merely happen while your code is inside the `around_save` block? Request timeouts are often handled by the webserver and your code might be unaware of it, even keep running.

Comment: Rails might be interpreting the operation inside the around_save as successful. Scenario 1. The around_save callback involves nested transactions or save points & the exception is rescued within one of the transactions & if the exception is not propagated, Rails might still commit the outer transaction.
2. If the exception is rescued somewhere within the callback chain or in the operation triggering the save, and not re-raised, the transaction might get committed.

Comment: Timeout happened because of this RACK_TIMEOUT_SERVICE_TIMEOUT constant configured. And the other callbacks after the one where this timeout was thrown were not executed. The request was killed at that particular line of code. No line of code after that was executed.

Answer (score 0):

It will be better if you put more information where you have defined models callbacks, validations, etc.

For example if you have some validations in before_save callback then it is important to `throw :abort` after adding the errors.